# Ubuntu won't boot after installing alongside windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I'll tell you my problem first then explain how it all happened. I'm a complete noob so please explain as easy as possible.

My windows 7 broke and I got Ubuntu 14.04 on a USB stick and used the live version. I installed ubuntu from the desktop alongside Windows 7. 2 new partitions were created one ~20gb, ~80gb. I shut down my computer and took out the usb. I start it again and nothing.

I checked to see if the 2 new partitions are there on live and yes they are.

I can't enter bios menu but I can enter the other one by pressing 'del' and decide what should boot in what order.  Without my usb I've only got 3 choices and none are ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

try using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), it's a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues.

Comment: Ok I try to install boot-repair from Ubuntu live version. I type: sudo add-apt-repository            but i get the line "Error: need a repository as argument"

Comment: you can't install softwares in live Ubuntu CD,  just use the 1st option

Comment: I tried with a cd but looks like I need to boot it from a usb instead. But i did get the notes on what's wrong if anything is.            paste.ubuntu.com/11041798